# Difference between $location.path and $window.location.href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have an AngularJS App where I am forcing a hard reload of the webpage to another location after an event. I have come across two methods of doing this:

```
return function(path) {
                $location.path(path);
                $window.location.reload(true);
            };
```

And:

```
return function(path) {
                $window.location.href = path;
                $window.location.reload(true);
            };
```

What are the differences between these two methods? Does one perform a harder reload than another?

Comment: Either should fail to reach the reload since the first statements likely loads a page before the reload takes place.  $window.location.reload(true); should be enough. Perhaps consider adding a random string to the URL

Comment: Hi, I am actually trying to reload to a different location that is passed into this function

Comment: Why would you need to? If you change to a diffferent location, make sure the location is not cached. For example by adding `"?rnd="+Date.now()` to the url